# How can I create g-suite add-ons or share Appscripts that I've written with others?

Tags: google-apps-script

Every two weeks my boss posts the shift schedule on google sheets app. Using Appscript I built a program that scans the schedule for my name and updates my google calendars app so I can have my shifts automatically updated. I copy and paste the schedule into a personal spreadsheet and then run the program.
Is there a simple way I can share the program with my co-workers?
I figured the easiest way to do it would be to build an add-on, that takes their personal g-suite and does the same thing, but I have no idea how to do that.

Does anyone know where I can find sources to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

One option here that would be a lot easier for you would be to make a template spreadsheet which has the code written in it, that your coworkers could make a copy of the spreadsheet and run the code. To make it more user-friendly, I would recommend using a UI menu to prompt them to enter their name, then it could scan the spreadsheet for their name, making calendar events accordingly.

Google has good documentation on publishing add-ons [as seen here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview), but it would be a much more tedious and time-consuming process.

Comment: And easy way to share scripts is the share thes accross a shared drive.  People with full access can remove your scripts and walk away with full ownership.